# Capture and save image with robotjs

Tags: node.js

I tried to capture and save an image from screen with robotjs (http://robotjs.io/) but when I open the file bitmap the image is not in a valid format. This is my code:

```
var robot = require("robotjs");
var fs = require("fs");
var size = 10;
var img = robot.screen.capture(0, 0, size, size);
fs.writeFileSync('img.bmp',img.image);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your `img.image` Buffer from [Robotjs](https://robotjs.io/docs/syntax#bitmap) is a **raw** buffer with pixels; not a BMP or PNG or any other format.

You should do some data conversion and probably save it using a library that supports writing to file (I do not see that in Robotjs).

Please look at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881698/4810295), which also uses `robot.screen.capture` and saves file to a PNG file using [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) library. That code answers your question too.

Answer (score 9):

Jimp supports converting [Raw Pixel Buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#creating-new-images) into PNG out-of-the-box and works a lot faster.

```
let robot = require("robotjs");
let Jimp = require('jimp');

const img = robot.screen.capture(0, 0, width, height).image;
new Jimp({data: img, width, height}, (err, image) => {
       image.write(fileName);
});
```

The image will be saved with the wrong colors. To fix it, you can use the following code:

```
function screenCaptureToFile2(robotScreenPic, path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const image = new Jimp(robotScreenPic.width, robotScreenPic.height);
            let pos = 0;
            image.scan(0, 0, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height, (x, y, idx) => {
                image.bitmap.data[idx + 2] = robotScreenPic.image.readUInt8(pos++);
                image.bitmap.data[idx + 1] = robotScreenPic.image.readUInt8(pos++);
                image.bitmap.data[idx + 0] = robotScreenPic.image.readUInt8(pos++);
                image.bitmap.data[idx + 3] = robotScreenPic.image.readUInt8(pos++);
            });
            image.write(path, resolve);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

var pic = robot.screen.capture();
screenCaptureToFile2(pic)
```