# get raw image in node js

Tags: node.js, request, buffer

I received raw image from api but how do I upload the raw image to my local folder? Here's my code, it just upload the raw image but save file is damaged and can't open

```
var path = "{HTTP://URL-TO-API/}";
request(path, function (errror, response, body) {
  var buffer = new Buffer(body, 'binary');
  fs.writeFile('out.png', buffer, function (error) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

here `console.log(body)` ->

[image: shown raw image in terminal]

and response headers  ->

```
headers: { date: 'Wed, 17 Jan 2018 01:41:36 GMT',
 server: 'Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)',
 connection: 'close',
 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
 'content-type': 'image/png' }
```

node ver: 8.9.2

Comment: you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881571/how-to-save-binary-buffer-to-png-file-in-nodejs)

Comment: @ManjeetThakur thank you for your answer but i solved it another way!

Comment: @ManjeetThakur if you already solved it, why not put your solution as an answer and close this question?